# How to create a boxplot from pre-aggregated/grouped data in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark, aggregate, boxplot

Using Matplotlib/Pandas/Seaborn, how would it be possible to build a boxplot from aggregated data instead of raw data?

Context: of millions of people I know their age and I would like to make a boxplot of this. Because I have millions of rows, I first agggregate my dataset using PySpark before proceeding with the plotting in Pandas. The result is that I have a dataset with the number of people having a certain age (e.g. 100K people of 18 years old).

I cannot seem to find an option in the Seaborn or maptlotlib packages. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution.

1. Aggregate the data using PySpark and store this data in a dictionary, using the key names. The dictionary `result` should look like this:

   `{'mean': 45.30698829299204,
   'med': 47.0,
   'q1': 27.0,
   'q3': 62.0,
   'iqr': 35.0,
   'whishi': 114,
   'whislo': 0,
   'fliers': array([[118], [118])
   }`
2. To plot you can use the matplotlib boxplot drawer function `bxp`, for example:

   `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 12))
   ax.bxp([result], showmeans = True, meanline = True)`

Details can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html).

Feel free to comment or answer a better solution if you have one.